# Distance between finite sets of points

Tags: metric-spaces

Denote the collection of all finite subsets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ as $\mathcal{S} = \{S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d: |S| < \infty \}$. What are ways to define distance metrics on $\mathcal{S}$ that can be efficiently computed? For instance, one could define 
$$
d(A, B) = \frac{1}{|A|\cdot|B|} \sum_{x\in A}\sum_{y\in B} \|x - y\|_2^2
$$
but I'm not sure if the triangle inequality is satisfied?

Comment: Could you be precise about what you mean by a distance metric?

Comment: @Matt: I mean a metric that satisfies the requirements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)

Comment: Could you use the discrete metric?

Comment: @Matt: What to is your definition of the discrete metric?

Comment: If $x = y$ then $d(x,y) = 0$. Otherwise, $d(x,y) = 1$.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, you are correct that that is a valid metric, but I was looking for a more practical option, since if the elements in $A$ and $B$ are in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $A\neq B$ with probability one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "more practical option". Perhaps you can elaborate on this a little in an edit to your original question?

Comment: Is [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @AdamFrancey; yes, that would definitely be an option.

Comment: Concerning the function $d(A,B)$ from your question, $d(A,A)=0$ iff $A$ is a one-point set, so $d$ is not a metric.